# Just what is a fileTypeHint in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, url, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

People of Earth,

During a recent forest foray, Boober Bunz came across an abandoned print-out of the [docs for the AVAudioPlayer object on IOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer).

I noticed that there is more than one type of constructor:

```
init(contentsOf: URL)
```

and...

```
init(contentsOf: URL, fileTypeHint: String?)
```

A URL object seems to contain any and all information needed in order to retreive a file:

```
let quack:URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Quack", withExtension: "wav")
```

See?  So Boober Bunz is confused because... what is the point of "hinting" about a file if the computer already has all the information it needs in order to find it?

This would be like saying... "Can I please get a Big Mac Meal super size?  Oh and here's a hint... it's food!"

What is a fileTypeHint? who needs one and why?

Can you explain zat?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you read the documentation for it? *"The utiString file type hint tells the parser what kind of sound data to expect so that data that may possibly be corrupt, can be successfully parsed."* where `utiString` is the internal name for the `fileTypeHint` label.

Comment: I didn't see that part... but that makes sense.

Comment: So it's really like "Can I get whatever is on the shelf back there in section B6, and I'll open my mouth and you can put it in my face... but only do it if it's food, please."